# Using ADODB.Recordset.Index when connecting to MySQL ODBC in VB6

Tags: mysql, sql, vb6, oledb, ado

I am working on a system that has been in use since the 90's. Written in VB6, it was originally setup to utilize an Access Database and the JET driver.

Now, since we have clients running up against the 2GB file size limit on Access DBs, we are looking into converting everything over to mySQL.

Unfortunately, everything in the system that was written prior to about 5 years ago is using this type of logic:

```
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
rst.ActiveConnection = cnn
rst.Open "table"
rst.Index = "index"
rst.Seek Array("field1", "field2"), adSeekFirstEQ
rst!field1 = "something new"
rst.Update
```

The newer code is using SQL commands like `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, etc.
So, what we're hoping to do is to phase in the new mySQL DBs for our clients - get them the DB setup but using all the old code.

The problem is that I can't use `Index` when using the SQL db... everything else seems to work fine except for that.
I get the error: `#3251: Current provider does not support the necessary interface for Index functionality.`

Is there something I'm missing? Is there another way to so a `Seek` when using SQL so that I can sort by my Index? Or will I have to go in and change the entire system and remove all the `Seek` logic - which is used THOUSANDS of times? This is particularly an issue for all of our Reports where we might have a Table with an Index where Col 1 is sorted ASC, Col 2 is sorted DESC, Col 3 is ASC again and I need to find the first 5 records where `Col 1 = X`. How else would you do it?

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen this technique of using Index/Seek with ADO! Most code I've seen opens recordsets by proving a complete SELECT query with an appropriate ORDER BY clause. I was going to suggest that you might be able to created linked tables in Access that point at the new MySQL database, but a cursory web search seems to imply that would not be supported.

Comment: Yes, all the new code that I've written uses SELECT and ORDER BY, it's just that all the old code doesn't, and it would take a ton of time and work to convert all the old code over - which we don't have right now.

Comment: Yeah, but if you want to move the data to MySQL I'm not sure you have much of a choice? Perhaps you could [split the Access database into multiple data files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257326/how-to-increase-ms-access-2007-database-size)? Looks like [`Seek` can be made to work](http://access.mvps.org/access/tables/tbl0006.htm) in that scenario.

Comment: We don't have any linked tables in our DB. We have split our DB into multiple files already, and it's not really feasible to keep doing that... I'm just looking for a solution to allow us to either use Index while pointing to an SQL DB, or to emulate the same kind of effect... basically, how can I have it open a table and sort it based on specific criteria (Col 1 Asc, Col 2 Desc, etc)?

Comment: ...I think I just figured out my own solution... at least partially...
If I open my recordset via a SELECT statement like: `SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY Col1 ASC, Col2 DESC`, that would effectively sort my Table the way I need it... only... I don't know if I can do a Seek afterwards... and if I can't, how can I jump to the first or last record that meets my criteria? An example would be: Go to the first record with an ID of X and a Date of Y so I can loop through and get all records for a given ID that happened after date Y...

Comment: WELL, I can't use an ADODB.Command with an SQL Query and then do a Seek, or an Update, or any of the things I would need to do... so... back to the drawing board...

Comment: Ultimately your best bet is to include an appropriate `WHERE` clause and an `ORDER BY` statement so you are only pulling back the necessary data to your app. But you can also use `Recordset.Filter` and `Recordset.Find` to accomplish some of those tasks on the client side.

Comment: just to play devil's advocate - maybe it's time to upgrade to modern frameworks.

Comment: @hubsonbropa I agree, but the time and effort required to do so is not currently available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, as you posted, the DB doesn't support Seek or Index, you're kind of out of luck as far as that is concerned.

However, if you really ***must*** use seek /index I'd suggest importing the result of the  SQL query into a local .mdb file and then using that to make the recordset work like the rest of the code expects.
This is slightly evil from a performance point of view, and honestly it may be better to replace all the seeks and index calls in the long run anyways, but at least it'll save you time coding.

For creating the local db you can do:

```
Function dimdbs(Temptable as String)
Dim tdfNew As TableDef
Dim prpLoop As Property
Dim strDbfullpath As String
Dim dbsn As Database
Dim idx As Index
Dim autofld As Field
'PARAMETERS: DBFULLPATH: FileName/Path of database to create

strDbfullpath = VBA.Environ$("TMP") & "\mydb.mdb"
If Dir(strDbfullpath) <> "" Then
           Set dbsn = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(strDbfullpath)
Else
    Set dbsn = DBEngine.CreateDatabase(strDbfullpath, dbLangGeneral)
End If

Set tdfNew = dbsn.CreateTableDef(Temptable)
With tdfNew
      ' Create fields and append them to the new TableDef
      ' object. This must be done before appending the
      ' TableDef object to the TableDefs collection of the
      ' database.
        Set autofld = .CreateField("autonum", dbLong)
        autofld.Attributes = dbAutoIncrField
        .Fields.Append autofld
        .Fields.Append .CreateField("foo", dbText, 3)
        .Fields.Append .CreateField("bar", dbLong)
        .Fields.Append .CreateField("foobar", dbText, 30)
        .Fields("foobar").AllowZeroLength = True
        Set idx = .CreateIndex("PrimaryKey")
        idx.Fields.Append .CreateField("autonum")
        idx.Unique = True
        idx.Primary = True
        .Indexes.Append idx

        Debug.Print "Properties of new TableDef object " & _
         "before appending to collection:"

      ' Enumerate Properties collection of new TableDef
      ' object.
      For Each prpLoop In .Properties
         On Error Resume Next
         If prpLoop <> "" Then Debug.Print "  " & _
           prpLoop.Name & " = " & prpLoop
         On Error GoTo 0
      Next prpLoop

      ' Append the new TableDef object to the Northwind
      ' database.
      If ObjectExists("Table", Temptable & "CompletedCourses", "Userdb") Then
        dbsn.Execute "Delete * FROM " & Temptable & "CompletedCourses"
      Else
      dbsn.TableDefs.Append tdfNew
      End If



      Debug.Print "Properties of new TableDef object " & _
         "after appending to collection:"

      ' Enumerate Properties collection of new TableDef
      ' object.
      For Each prpLoop In .Properties
         On Error Resume Next
         If prpLoop <> "" Then Debug.Print "  " & _
           prpLoop.Name & " = " & prpLoop
         On Error GoTo 0
      Next prpLoop

    End With
    Set idx = Nothing
    Set autofld = Nothing
End Function
```

to find and delete it later you can use the following:

```
Function DeleteAllTempTables(strTempString As String, Optional tmpdbname As String = "\mydb.mdb", Optional strpath As String = "%TMP%")
Dim dbs2 As Database
Dim t As dao.TableDef, I As Integer
Dim strDbfullpath
If strpath = "%TMP%" Then
    strpath = VBA.Environ$("TMP")
End If
strDbfullpath = strpath & tmpdbname
If Dir(strDbfullpath) <> "" Then
    Set dbs2 = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(strDbfullpath)
Else
    Exit Function
End If
        strTempString = strTempString & "*"
      For I = dbs2.TableDefs.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
         Set t = dbs2.TableDefs(I)
         If t.Name Like strTempString Then
            dbs2.TableDefs.Delete t.Name
         End If
      Next I
dbs2.Close

End Function
```

To import from SQL to that DB you'll have to get the recordset and add each record in using a for loop (unless it's a fixed ODBC connection, i think you can import directly but I don't have example code)

```
Dim formrst As New ADODB.recordset
Set mysqlconn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim dbsRst As recordset
Dim dbs As Database
'opens the ADODB connection to my database
Call openConnect(mysqlconn)
'calls the above function to create the temp database
'Temptable is defined as a form-level variable so it can be unique to this form 
'and other forms/reports don't delete it
Call dimdbs(Temptable)
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM [" & Temptable & "] IN '" & VBA.Environ$("TMP") & "\mydb.mdb'"
Set dbs = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(VBA.Environ$("TMP") & "\mydb.mdb")
Set dbsRst = dbs.OpenRecordset(Temptable)

Set formrst.ActiveConnection = mysqlconn
Call Selectquery(formrst, strSQL & strwhere & SQLorderby, adLockReadOnly, adOpenForwardOnly)
With formrst
    Do Until .EOF
            dbsRst.AddNew
            dbsRst!foo = !foo
            dbsRst!bar = !bar
            dbsRst!foobar = !foobar
            dbsRst.Update
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With
dbsRst.Close
Set dbsRst = Nothing
dbs.Close
Set formrst = Nothing
```

You'll have to re-import the data on save or on form close at the end, but at least that will only need one SQL statement, or you can do it directly with the ODBC connection.

This is by far less than optimal but at least you can couch all this code inside one or two extra function calls and it won't disturb the original logic.

I have to give huge credit to Allen Browne, I pulled this code from all over the place but most my code probably comes from or has been inspired by his site (http://allenbrowne.com/)

Comment: I'm not sure how practical this will be in the real world, but it is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Who wants to use VB6? Nevertheless...

When you do not specify Provider, you can't use Index property. As far as i know **only OleDb for MS Jet supports **Seek** method and **Index** property**.
Please read this:

**Seek** method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675109%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**Index** property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675255%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**ConnectionString** property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675810%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**Provider** property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

For further information, please see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**[EDIT]**
After your comments...
I would **strongly recommend** to [download and install Visual Studio Express Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx) and use VB.NET instead VB6. Than  install [ADO.NET MySQL Connector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx) and re-write application, using the newest technology rather than torturing yourself with ADODB objects, etc.

Examples:
[Connecting to MySQL databases using VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/493133/Connecting-to-MySQL-databases-using-VB-NET)
**[/EDIT]**

Comment: So, I think what you're saying is that there's no way to connect to an mySQL DB and still retain anything close to the `Index/Seek` functionality? If I'm connecting to SQL, it HAS to use SQL Queries (`SELECT`, `UPDATE`, etc)?

Comment: Not necesarry... What i'm trying to say is that you need to check this: **Use the _Supports(adSeek)_ method to determine whether the underlying provider supports Seek, and the _Supports(adIndex)_ method to determine whether the provider supports indexes.**

Comment: I already know that they do not support Seek and Index, but what I'm saying is that I have about 20,000 places in the code that currently use those methods - and then proceed as if those functions worked, and I'm trying to figure out what I can do to at least come close to working the same way so I can make minimal code changes...

Comment: Yes, there is a chance... If some part of code is used many times, it should be moved to separate procedure or function.

Comment: We are using functions, but just changing the function isn't going to solve any problems...
We have our function `DBSeek` which is setup to use the `Index` and `Seek` and then return the Recordset. So we have a ton of places all over that call this function. First, I don't know how I can change this function so that it can do a command with `SELECT` or `UPDATE` AND somehow be able to tell how the index was setup so that the SELECT still works the same, and then all the places that call this function which act as if it were opened via Seek and won't work once it changes...

Comment: As soon as it's feasable for us to migrate our entire project - which has taken about 15 years to get to this point, we will be looking at VB.NET - but that's probably another 5-10 years away, as there are more things that need to be changed and added to the system right now for people currently using it.